# Link between XHTML pages?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces

I use `<h:outputLink value="home.jsf"><h:outputText value="Home"/></h:outputLink>` to move between my XHTML pages or so called Facelets.

Personally though I would prefer to do the same thing though using the `<h:commandButton>...</h:commandButton>`. The reason is that it is easier to place a background image into a button than to create a CSS workaround with the *outputLink* and the *outputText*.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: I very much like how to's as well. Do you have a link describing this matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax for `<h:commandButton>` :

```
<h:commandButton action="#{yourBean.action}" image="yourPic.png" value="your text on the button" styleClass="yourCSS" />
```

You can then create an action in your bean to redirect on another view :

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("your destination");
```

You can get your application URL with :

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestContextPath();
```